# Cursor or looping for stored procedure

Tags: sql, loops, cursor

I have a table that has records in it.  One of the fields is quantity field.   For that row i have to put the same line however many times is in the quantity field into another table.    I also have to get from a third table the number assignment making each of the rows unique.

so

tblrecnumassignments --assigns number

claimstoexplode--rows to explode with quantity per row

claims --where each record is going to reside

this is my three tables.

I can get one row inserted the number of quantity.  But it uses same rec num and how do i get it to go to the next row in claims to explode.  I'm so lost and my boss is after me to finish this.

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

declare @recnum as varchar(100), 
        @lngrecnum as varchar(100), 
        @vwclaimscount as int, 
        @count as int

select @vwclaimscount = COUNT([dlr num]) from claimstoexplode --outer loop number
select @lngrecnum = MAX([rec num] + 1) from tmpClaims_RecNumAssignment 

print @lngrecnum

select @count = claimstoexplode.qty from dbo.claimstoexplode --inner loop




begin

if @vwclaimscount > 0


insert into tmpClaims_RecNumAssignment
( operator, dtmadded)
values ('explode5', getdate())


insert into tmpclaims1 
([Dlr Num]
   ,[Promo]
   ,[Trans Code]
   ,[Proc Date]
   ,[Control Num]
   ,[Invoice Num]
   ,[Clm Date]
   ,[Amt Claimed]
   ,[Amt Appr]
   ,[Amt Paid]
   ,[Ad From]
   ,[Ad To]
   ,[Media]
   ,[Media Desc]
   ,[Audit 1]
   ,[Audit 2]
   ,[Audit 3]
   ,[Audit 4]
   ,[Audit 5]
   ,[Audit 6]
   ,[Prod Code 1]
   ,[Prod Code 1 %]
   ,[Prod Code 1 Amt]
   ,[Prod Code 1 Adv Amt]
   ,[Prod Code 2]
   ,[Prod Code 2 %]
   ,[Prod Code 2 Amt]
   ,[Prod Code 2 Adv Amt]
   ,[Comment]
   ,[Received Date]
   ,[Last Modified]
   ,[Ratio]
   ,[Number Of Ads]
   ,[Amt Applied]
   ,[UM]
   ,[Audited Amt]
   ,[Rated Ads]
   ,[Branch Number]
   ,[Operator]
   ,[Bal Pending]
   ,[Paid From Pending]
   ,[Store Num]
   ,[Clm Spec 1]
   ,[Clm Spec 2]
   ,[Status]
   ,[Rec Num]
   ,[Doc Type] 
   ,locked

)

select 
[dlr num]
,prognum
,'X'
,GETDATE()
,'0'
,''
,[received date]
,round([claimed amt]/qty,2)
,'0'
,'0'
,dtmfrom
,dtmto
,'9'
,  dbo.Promos.[Promo Misc 1]
         ,'01'
,''
,''
,''
,''
,''
   ,[Product]

,'0'
,'0'
,'0'
,bundlemodel
,'0'
,'0'
,'0'
,''
,[received date]
,''

,'100'
,'1'
,'0'
,'0'
,'0'
,'0'
,'0'
,claimstoexplode.operator
,'0'
,'0'
,'0'
,LEFT(reference,10)
,[record number]
,'1'
, @lngrecnum ,'L' ,'1' from claimstoexplode inner join
dbo.promos ON dbo.Promos.Promo = dbo.claimstoexplode.prognum

set @vwclaimscount = @vwclaimscount - 1
set @lngrecnum = @lngrecnum + 1
set @count = @count - 1
```

End

Comment: You may get more answers if you give some example data : if you show an example of what you start with, and the results you desire, then we may be able to understand your English description of the business logic.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....